# Replace individual array value with loop in PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

So, here is the scenario, suppose I have multiple values inside $**altName** (more than 2). 
Now what here I am trying to do is locate those values using  **$altName[0], $altName[1]**(indexing) and assign into **AltName** but the problem here is every new value in $**altName** required new variable. 
ex: **domain3.com** required **$altName[2]** which I don't want.

```
$altName = array("domain1.com", "domain2.com");
$postData = [

        'AltName' => [
            $altName[0],$altName[1]
        ]

    ];

var_dump($postData);
```

Q. My questing is that possible to use a loop? I tried foreach but I got syntax error.

```
'AltName' => [
            //loop values here from an array (domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com)
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$altName  = ["domain1.com", "domain2.com"];
$postData = ['AltName' => $altName];
```

Or:

```
$postData['AltName'] = $altName;
```

Comment: @ns789, am I missing something in your question?

Comment: No, the answer is perfect! this is what exactly I am looking for.